# export data from active worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, export

I have produced an excel workbook with single worksheet as a template for end user. The workbook will save and quit with filename created based on 3 cell values. Can I make this workbook template automatically exporting certain data to another workbook? Another things is, can the new exported data have automatically new row to insert the data into the workbook/worksheet destination? I have checked related excel forum and found the code must have a filename to export data and I stuck on it.   Here the code that I have tried:

---

`Sub ExportData()`

```
Sheets("Master").Range("C95").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Summary").Range("B9")
Sheets("Master").Range("E97").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Summary").Range("C9")
Sheets("Master").Range("T9").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Summary").Range("D9")
Sheets("Master").Range("T11").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Summary").Range("E9")
Sheets("Master").Range("E15").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Summary").Range("F9")
x.Close
End Sub
```

-----------(other code that I've tried)--------------------------------

```
Sub ExportData()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim s As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("Template")
Set s = Workbooks.Open("Summary Report")

s.Sheets("Summary").Range("C95").Value = x.Sheets("Master").Range("B9")
s.Sheets("Summary").Range("E97").Value = x.Sheets("Master").Range("C9")
s.Sheets("Summary").Range("T9").Value = x.Sheets("Master").Range("D9") 
s.Sheets("Summary").Range("T11").Value = x.Sheets("Master").Range("E9") 
s.Sheets("Summary").Range("E15").Value = x.Sheets("Master").Range("F9")
x.Close
End Sub
```

---